# find XY values of Great Britain and Northen Ireland

Tags: openlayers, latitude-longitude, xy

I'm using Openlayers 3 to show the map of Great Britain and Northern Ireland. For that I need to provide the extent values of GB and Northern Ireland. I tried in google and couldn't find a proper resource for grid locations in GB and Northern Ireland.

I need to provide the extent values as in below format.

(minX,minY – maxX,maxY): -521611.7877215, -99060.2018315805 - 1107515.6274664556, 1234593.14792

Can someone let me know the correct grid locations for GB and Northern Ireland or a proper source to find those please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you use the very useful website, which **, as @iant has pointed out**, is provided by [Klokan Technologies GmbH](http://epsg.io/27700). The official coordinate reference system for the GB is 27700, if you plug that in, you will see the WGS 84 as well as projected (by which they mean 3857, aka Spherical Mercator), which is what is used by most global tile sets you are likely to use in Open Layers, Leaflet and similar. There is also a [transform coordinates page](http://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=27700&t_srs=3857), which you could use to extend the bounds, setting the appropriate target SRS, which from what you have posted above, would seem to be 3857.

As you can see on that page, the bounds for **WGS 84** are:

> -8.74 49.81
>
> 1.84 60.9

and for **EPSG:3857**

> -84667.14 11795.97
>
> 608366.68 1230247.30

Comment: Actually 27700 is a GB not UK crs so Northern Ireland falls outside its defined range. The island of Ireland has it's own grid EPSG:29902

Comment: @iant, yes, very true, I should know, because I have to convert between 29902 and 27700 all the time. Thanks for correction. I am constantly confusing GB and UK.

Comment: Also epsg.io is provided by Klokan Technologies GmbH not EPSG, the EPSG's site is http://www.epsg-registry.org/ (and much harder to use)

Comment: Edited. It really is a great website.

Answer (score 2):

[The Humanitarian Data Exchange website](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/bounding-boxes-for-countries) offers a possible source for country bounding boxes (in CRS WGS84).

- GB: [48.500, -13.683, 64.067, 3.858]
- Ireland: [51.367, -10.683, 55.433, -4.000]

There is also a [GitHub project](https://github.com/azurro/country-bounding-boxes) that provides boundingboxes in JSON format extracted from OSM.

- GB: [49.674, -8.1775098, 61.061, 2.0919117]
- Ireland: [51.222, -11.0133787, 55.636, -5.6582362]

The coordinates differ quite a lot. You should have a look which one satisfies your needs. There are more data sources like these. Just google for country bounding boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Which coordinate system are you working in? I always use spatialreference.org whenever I need to look up come coordinates. The OSGB page is [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/).

Bounding box shown on that page:

> WGS84 Bounds: -7.5600, 49.9600, 1.7800, 60.8400
>
> Projected Bounds: 1393.0196, 13494.9764, 671196.3657, 1230275.0454

Comment: Projected to what CRS? If it is 3857, there should be some negative numbers in there for the UK, as it crosses the central meridian. I suspect that is a UTM coordinate system you have put up, which is most definitely not going to be useful to someone using Open Layers.

Comment: Well, as I said it's from the OSGB page, so that would suggest projected to OSGB. As other commenters have suggested, this would just be a GB bounding box and does not include NI.

Comment: The official extents of OSGB, according to the OS themselves, is 0,0 to 700000, 1344000. The OP is clearly looking for 3857, as they are working in OpenLayers and from the extents posted. So, sure, what you posted does represent the somewhat incorrect extents of the 27700 bounding box.